# I need to deserialize a complex JSON with multiple classes in POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I know I'm doing something wrong, but, am struggling to figure it out. please help.

Jackson Json Conf Camel Blueprint Spring:

```
<bean class="com.sage.entities.MyPojo" id="myPojo"/>
<dataFormats> 
<json disableFeatures="FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES"
                enableFeatures="ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT,ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT"
                id="AJson2Pojo4"
                library="Jackson" prettyPrint="true" unmarshalTypeName="com.sage.entities.MyPojo"/>       
</dataFormats>
<unmarshal><custom ref="AJson2Pojo4"/></unmarshal>
```

my story :
I am successfully deserializing a complex JSON, to a point. and at this point I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. thank you in advance.

my POJO. This Works! but I need to go deeper with inner classes.

```
public class MyPojo{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 202003211122L;

    public MyPojo() {}

      private String httpStatus;
      Payload PayloadObject;
      ArrayList<Object> errorMessages = new ArrayList<Object>();

     // Getter Methods 

      public String getHttpStatus() {
        return httpStatus;
      }

      public Payload getPayload() {
        return PayloadObject;
      }

     // Setter Methods 

      public void setHttpStatus( String httpStatus ) {
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
      }

      public void setPayload( Payload payloadObject ) {
        this.PayloadObject = payloadObject;
      }

    public class Payload {
      ArrayList<Object> internalRecords = new ArrayList<Object>();
      ArrayList<Object> records = new ArrayList<Object>();
      ArrayList<Object> timeSeriesRecords = new ArrayList<Object>();

      public ArrayList<Object> getTimeSeriesRecords(){
          return timeSeriesRecords;
      }
      public void setTimeSeriesRecords(ArrayList<Object> timeSeriesRecords) {
          this.timeSeriesRecords = timeSeriesRecords;
      }
      public ArrayList<Object> getInternalRecords(){
          return internalRecords;
      }
      public ArrayList<Object> getRecords(){
          return records;
      }
      public void setInternalRecords(ArrayList<Object> internalRecords) {
          this.internalRecords =  internalRecords;
      }
      public void setRecords(ArrayList<Object> records) {
          this.records = records;
      }
    }
}
```

This works, deserializes the JSON to this. this is just one object.

```
timeSeriesRecords: {name=706247, timestamps=[2020-06-05T08:28:59, 2020-06-05T08:53:17, 2020-06-05T10:55:34, 2020-06-05T12:57:43, 2020-06-05T14:57:44, 2020-06-04T22:37:16, 2020-06-04T23:05:51, 2020-06-05T01:07:29, 2020-06-05T03:07:31], data=[{name=flight_phase, data=[TAKEOFF, CRUISE, CRUISE, CRUISE, CRUISE, TAKEOFF, CRUISE, CRUISE, CRUISE], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=DPOIL, data=[null, -15.4604, -13.8422, -13.2137, -13.5186, null, -16.8422, -14.7853, -13.5696], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=POIL, data=[null, 72.4604, 69.8422, 69.2137, 69.5186, null, 69.8422, 67.7853, 67.5696], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=GN2MC, data=[null, 1.66469, 2.19799, 2.05127, 2.29911, null, 2.20363, 2.40703, 2.38929], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=DELN1, data=[6.23079, null, null, null, null, -0.370548], arraySizes=[6]}, {name=message_date_time, data=[2020-06-05T08:28:59, 2020-06-05T08:53:17, 2020-06-05T10:55:34, 2020-06-05T12:57:43, 2020-06-05T14:57:44, 2020-06-04T22:37:16, 2020-06-04T23:05:51, 2020-06-05T01:07:29, 2020-06-05T03:07:31], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=EGTHDM, data=[11.9738, null, null, null, null, -0.844012], arraySizes=[6]}, {name=SLOATL, data=[33.4591, null, null, null, null, 29.7589], arraySizes=[6]}, {name=IAIE, data=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=GWFM, data=[null, 4.94427, 4.93224, 7.15636, 5.84145, null, 5.81955, 5.8618, 5.92097], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=IB, data=[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=SATSLF, data=[53.6306, null, null, null, null, 73.9836], arraySizes=[6]}, {name=PCN12, data=[103.357, 96.3, 93.3, 92.6, 92.8, 111.38, 93, 90.4, 89.9], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=BRAT, data=[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=TATSL, data=[16.6171, null, null, null, null, 28.2083], arraySizes=[6]}, {name=IAIWG, data=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=DTAMB, data=[-2.98298, null, null, null, null, 8.32425], arraySizes=[6]}, {name=YN1MOD, data=[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=WBNOM, data=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=VSVNOM, data=[null, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, 0, 0, 0], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=flight_report_id, data=[556612329, 556614998, 556624200, 556636413, 556647711, 556563236, 556565278, 556574200, 556586659], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=DELFN, data=[10.1342, null, null, null, null, -0.525884], arraySizes=[6]}, {name=SATSL, data=[12.017, null, null, null, null, 23.3242], arraySizes=[6]}, {name=DEGT, data=[null, -15.2332, -14.9595, -4.57673, -5.50067, null, -17.8259, -9.75815, -8.17455], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=PCN1K, data=[103.526, 101.35, 99.541, 99.5841, 99.0076, 109.264, 99.0255, 97.4138, 96.875], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=TATSLF, data=[61.9108, null, null, null, null, 82.7749], arraySizes=[6]}, {name=GEGTMC, data=[null, 42.2332, 41.9595, 31.5767, 32.5007, null, 44.8259, 36.7582, 35.1745], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=PCN12I, data=[104.3, 96.3, 93.3, 92.6, 92.8, 112.5, 93, 90.4, 89.9], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=GPCN25, data=[null, 2.63531, 2.10201, 2.24873, 2.00089, null, 2.09637, 1.89297, 1.91071], arraySizes=[9]}, {name=processed_date_time, data=[2020-06-05T08:29:22, 2020-06-05T08:53:54, 2020-06-05T10:56:41, 2020-06-05T12:59:12, 2020-06-05T14:58:32, 2020-06-04T22:37:38, 2020-06-04T23:06:44, 2020-06-05T01:08:04, 2020-06-05T03:10:15], arraySizes=[9]}]}
```

So, the timeSeriesRecords are stored as an mal-formed JSON - seen above. 
I need access to the inner records, name, data, etc.., all now mal-formed JSON.  I was going to add another POJO to then put this in, but I can't because it is a mal-formed JSON.  I need to put this also in POJO.

so I created additional classes in my JSON POJO. So, I changed my POJO to this... added inner classes to capture the needed peices.

```
public class MyPojo {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 202003211122L;

    public MyPojo() {}

      private String httpStatus;
      Payload PayloadObject;
      ArrayList<Object> errorMessages = new ArrayList<Object>();

     // Getter Methods 

      public String getHttpStatus() {
        return httpStatus;
      }

      public Payload getPayload() {
        return PayloadObject;
      }

     // Setter Methods 

      public void setHttpStatus( String httpStatus ) {
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
      }

      public void setPayload( Payload payloadObject ) {
        this.PayloadObject = payloadObject;
      }

        public class Data
        {
            @JsonProperty("name")
            private String name;
            @JsonProperty("arraySizes")
            private ArrayList<Integer> arraySizes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            @JsonProperty("data")
            private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

            public Data() {}

            @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
            public Data(@JsonProperty("name") String name,
                                    @JsonProperty("arraySizes") ArrayList<Integer> arraySizes,
                                    @JsonProperty("data") ArrayList<String> data) {
                this.name = name;
                this.arraySizes = arraySizes;
                this.data = data;
            }

            public void setName(String name){
                this.name = name;
            }
            public String getName(){
                return this.name;
            }
            public void setArraySizes(ArrayList<Integer> arraySizes){
                this.arraySizes = arraySizes;
            }
            public List<Integer> getArraySizes(){
                return this.arraySizes;
            }
            public void setData(ArrayList<String> data){
                this.data = data;
            }
            public List<String> getData(){
                return this.data;
            }
        }

        public class TimeSeriesRecords
        {
            @JsonProperty("name")
            private String name;
            @JsonProperty("timestamps")
            private ArrayList<String> timestamps = new ArrayList<String>();
            @JsonProperty("data")
            private ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();

            @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
            public TimeSeriesRecords(@JsonProperty("name") String name,
                                    @JsonProperty("timestamps") ArrayList<String> timestamps,
                                    @JsonProperty("data") ArrayList<Data> data) {
                this.name = name;
                this.timestamps = timestamps;
                this.data = data;
            }

            public void setName(String name){
                this.name = name;
            }
            public String getName(){
                return this.name;
            }
            public void setTimestamps(ArrayList<String> timestamps){
                this.timestamps = timestamps;
            }
            public List<String> getTimestamps(){
                return this.timestamps;
            }
            public void setData(ArrayList<Data> data){
                this.data = data;
            }
            public List<Data> getData(){
                return this.data;
            }
        }

    public class Payload {
      ArrayList<Object> internalRecords = new ArrayList<Object>();
      ArrayList<Object> records = new ArrayList<Object>();
      ArrayList<TimeSeriesRecords> timeSeriesRecords = new ArrayList<TimeSeriesRecords>();

      public ArrayList<TimeSeriesRecords> getTimeSeriesRecords(){
          return timeSeriesRecords;
      }
      public void setTimeSeriesRecords(ArrayList<TimeSeriesRecords> timeSeriesRecords) {
          this.timeSeriesRecords = timeSeriesRecords;
      }
      public ArrayList<Object> getInternalRecords(){
          return internalRecords;
      }
      public ArrayList<Object> getRecords(){
          return records;
      }
      public void setInternalRecords(ArrayList<Object> internalRecords) {
          this.internalRecords =  internalRecords;
      }
      public void setRecords(ArrayList<Object> records) {
          this.records = records;
      }
    }
}
```

but now I am getting the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Type: [null]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:517)[123:com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind:2.6.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(TypeFactory.java:470)[123:com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind:2.6.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.constructCreatorProperty(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:842)[123:com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind:2.6.3]
```

I have tried several minor variations, however, I can't get past this error.

please show me what I'm doing wrong. thank you!

a TEST JSON

```
{
        "httpStatus": "OK",
        "payload": {
            "internalRecords": [],
            "records": [
                {
                    "name": "aircraft_id",
                    "arraySizes": [
                        412
                    ],
                    "data": [
                        "3848",
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "engine_family",
                    "arraySizes": [
                        412
                    ],
                    "data": [
                        "CFM56-7",
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "engine_type",
                    "arraySizes": [
                        412
                    ],
                    "data": [
                        "CFM56-7B27E/B1F",
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "aircraft_type",
                    "arraySizes": [
                        412
                    ],
                    "data": [
                        "B737-900ER",
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "timeSeriesRecords": [
                {
                    "name": "31340D",
                    "timestamps": [
                        "2018-12-17T19:37:18",
                        "2018-12-17T19:37:18",
                        "2018-12-17T20:13:18",
                        "2018-12-18T14:38:43"
                    ],
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "name": "flight_phase",
                            "arraySizes": [
                                15
                            ],
                            "data": [
                                "TAKEOFF",
                                "TAKEOFF",
                                "CRUISE",
                                "CRUISE",
                                "TAKEOFF",
                                "TAKEOFF",
                                "CRUISE",
                                "CRUISE",
                                "TAKEOFF",
                                "TAKEOFF",
                                "CRUISE",
                                "CRUISE",
                                "TAKEOFF",
                                "TAKEOFF",
                                "CRUISE"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "message_date_time",
                            "arraySizes": [
                                15
                            ],
                            "data": [
                                "2018-12-17T19:37:18",
                                "2018-12-17T19:37:18",
                                "2018-12-17T20:13:18",
                                "2018-12-17T22:30:36"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "IAIE",
                            "arraySizes": [
                                15
                            ],
                            "data": [
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "IB",
                            "arraySizes": [
                                15
                            ],
                            "data": [
                                "1",
                                "1",
                                "1",
                                "1",
                                "1",
                                "1",
                                "1",
                                "1",
                                "1",
                                "1",
                                "1",
                                "1",
                                "1",
                                "1",
                                "1"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "eposition",
                            "arraySizes": [
                                15
                            ],
                            "data": [
                                1,
                                2,
                                1,
                                2,
                                1,
                                2,
                                1,
                                2,
                                1,
                                2,
                                1,
                                2,
                                1,
                                2,
                                2
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "IAIWG",
                            "arraySizes": [
                                15
                            ],
                            "data": [
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0",
                                "0"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "flight_report_id",
                            "arraySizes": [
                                15
                            ],
                            "data": [
                                "389660813",
                                "389660814",
                                "389667535",
                                "389668530",
                                "389700831"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "engine_serial_number",
                            "arraySizes": [
                                15
                            ],
                            "data": [
                                "802222",
                                "802333",
                            ]
                        },
                         {
                            "name": "processed_date_time",
                            "arraySizes": [
                                15
                            ],
                            "data": [
                                "2018-12-17T19:38:04",
                                "2018-12-17T19:38:49",
                                "2018-12-17T20:15:22",
                                "2018-12-17T20:16:17",
                                "2018-12-17T22:03:29",
                                "2018-12-18T14:51:31"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "errorMessages": []
    }
```

Hello, ok, I found this link

```
http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_411.html
```

I changed the inner classes to be static, and now I'm not getting the error anymore, 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Type: [null]

but now I feel even more an idiot, I'm openning the books again :) - 
I don't know how to access the static classes from another class ???
I can't access the Payload class

tried this so far,

```
    AviationEntities4 ae = 
    exchange.getIn().getBody(AviationEntities4.class);
    Payload pl = ae.getPayload(); 
    String ok = ae.getHttpStatus();
    log.info("HttpStatus: " + ok);

//      AviationEntities4 payload = ae.getPayload();
//      AviationEntities4.Payload payload = ae.getPayload();
//      Payload pl = ae.getPayload();
```

thank you again so much for taking time for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link, article, information has solved my problem and given better understanding on inner classes and Jackson.

```
http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_411.html
```

2 ways to go,

1. make inner classes static
2. put inner classes in their own Class

it worked using static, and it worked iwth inner classes as their own class and then extened of course.  so I went with # 2.  it works as expected.

thank you COWTOWNCODER !!!